# Using permission/resource token for rest-api cosmos db azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Environment for resource/permission token creation:
nodejs v14
@azure/cosmos

Environment to fetch docs:
rest api postman client windows machine

I am getting error when trying to fetch GET docs using created permission with below PermissionDefinition as:

```
{ 
       id: "key-name", permissionMode: "All",             
       resource: "dbs/<db-name>/colls/<col-name>/docs/*",
       resourcePartitionKey: ["partition-key"]           
}
```

Also tried resource id as "dbs//colls//docs"
But getting same error, I am able to success fetch collection info with url as

```
https://{{DocumentDBHost}}/dbs/<db-name>/colls/<coll-name>
```

Below is error when trying to get docs from collection through rest api using permission resource token as:

```
{
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Insufficient permissions provided in the authorization header for the corresponding request. Please retry with another authorization header.\r\nActivityId: d6fe0b9e-c0a2-42a4-9378-50ccf1613aa7, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0"
}
```

using url as:
// to read specific doc

```
https://{{DocumentDBHost}}/dbs/<db-name>/colls/<coll-name>/docs/<doc-id>
```

// to read all docs in collection

```
https://{{DocumentDBHost}}/dbs/<db-name>/colls/<coll-name>/docs
```

Perparing auth token as

```
var permToken = "type=resource&ver=1&sig=UVlXYH0zKJyubcH9LAsBiw==;w7eUSmBFoA4dpcGNgV3Lm3kbFUE42IixXPEI2LVEr******************BPeWGl2pnkfN6V7FLX0leF/9WeDzUz06rq3po48jUSws5hNY8aR9LqMdSgwE1U4ygNbINMNe****************************v+u/ge9lKy10eZObL1u4FQMiE=;"

auth = encodeURIComponent(permToken);
```

So, doing encoding uri also on token got through permission

Other headers added to rest api are as follows:

```
[{"key":"Accept","value":"application/json","enabled":true},{"key":"x-ms-version","value":"2015-12-16","enabled":true},{"key":"Authorization","value":"{{authToken}}","enabled":true},{"key":"x-ms-date","value":"{{RFC1123time}}","enabled":true},{"key":"x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey","value":"[\"dl\"]","type":"text","enabled":true}]
```

Kindly pass detailed rest api doc when using resource/permission token, if there is any any change in specs. I already shared secondary key are success working for authorization part for same api request to CosmosDB

Comment: I really have no idea what's going on here, but please stop comment-spamming with the same comment - over a dozen times??? (and you cannot random-tag people like this - nobody is getting alerted). You shouldn't be tagging anyone anyway - this is not how this site works. Also: Please be mindful of tags: the description of the `cosmos` tag explicitly states that it is unrelated to Cosmos DB.

Comment: Please take the time to edit your question to be more specific, with all needed details. You've mentioned using node, for example, but then you talk about using a REST call - ok, please show all details of the that call (without specific auth key). As written, it's not clear what specific issue you're having, or why.

Comment: Thanks David,

I have created permission using node environment web application running at azure backend,

Then, trying to use the resource token generate in rest api interface of cosmos db to fetch docs in given col.

I am able to success fetch docs using primary/secondary key flow, but just need to increase my control with added security of resource token, as they are more specific to resource

I hope this clarifies my query

Comment: Docs for using resource tokens is here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data?tabs=using-primary-key#resource-tokens. btw, there is a sample using our Node.js SDK here, https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/master/src/auth.ts